# Async/Await in nestjs example

Tags: typescript, async-await, nestjs

I have a question, in the example 23-graphql-code-first in the file recipes.resolver.ts https://github.com/nestjs/nest/blob/master/sample/23-graphql-code-first/src/recipes/recipes.resolver.ts in some places it uses await and in others it does not.

**with await**

```
@Mutation(returns => Recipe)
  async addRecipe(
    @Args('newRecipeData') newRecipeData: NewRecipeInput,
  ): Promise<Recipe> {
    const recipe = await this.recipesService.create(newRecipeData);
    pubSub.publish('recipeAdded', { recipeAdded: recipe });
    return recipe;
  }
```

**without await**

```
@Query(returns => [Recipe])
  recipes(@Args() recipesArgs: RecipesArgs): Promise<Recipe[]> {
    return this.recipesService.findAll(recipesArgs);
  }
```

what are the differences?

Answer (score 0):

In the latter example:

```
@Query(returns => [Recipe])
  recipes(@Args() recipesArgs: RecipesArgs): Promise<Recipe[]> {
    return this.recipesService.findAll(recipesArgs);
  }
```

The function does not do any work. The return value of `findAll()` is a promise itself. This function just passes the returned promise forward to the caller. Thus, there is no need to `await` any IO or work to be performed.